# how to play an avmutablecomposition on mpmovieplayer?

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, avassetexportsession, avmutablecomposition

i have thoroughly scanned google for this , is their a way to play avmutablecomposition on mpmovieplayercontroller , they have to be init with a URL so i guess the real question is, is  their a temporary URL for avmutablecomposition or can we create one using avassetexportsession and if user doesnot like it could be deleted then?

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 8.0 you could use AVPlayerViewController - https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/index.html

```
AVPlayerViewController *playerVC = ....; //initialize the playerViewController 
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:[mutableComposition copy]]; //make an immutable copy of the mutableComposition
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[playerVC setPlayer:player];
```